# Swift error : '(AFHTTPRequestOperation! , NSError? ) -> is not convertible to '((AFHTTPRequestOperation? , NSError) -> Void?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am using AFNetworking in swift and i am facing a problem in converting following code to swift

**Objective C**

```
[client GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nullable operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

}];
```

**Swift Code** (gives error)

```
self.client.GET(url,
        parameters: nil,
        success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in

        },
        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in

    })
```

Comment: It says `NSError * _Nonnull error` so don't pass an optional error object. i.e use `(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError) in`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
self.client.GET(url, parameters: nil, success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation, responseObject: AnyObject?) in

}, failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation?, error: NSError) in

})
```

Comment: As a side not check out https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire its a pure swift implementation, but doesn't have all the functionality of `AFNetworking`, so sometimes not the best fit.